# search for the same cell in a different DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a section of code that loops through a second `DataGridView`, trying to match the same index number from the main `DataGridVew` that the user interacts with:

```
Private Sub AllegationsDataGridView_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AllegationsDataGridView.CellEnter
        Try
            Dim currentcolumn As DataGridViewColumn =
        AllegationsDataGridView.Columns(AllegationsDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex)
            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In parentgrid.Rows
                If row.Cells.Item(0).Value = AllegationsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value Then
                    parentgrid.CurrentCell = parentgrid(0, row.Index)
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message)
        End Try
endsub:

    End Sub
```

The problem is is that the datasource could potentially be thousands and thousands of entries, and I don't want this to loop through everysingle row until it finds the match. I wondered if there was a quicker way to approach this? The only examples I have seen when searching all use either a `For Each Row` approach, or a `Loop Until` approach, which would still present the same issue.

Comment: Did you manually populate the DGVs or do they use a DataSource?  Iterating rows and cells will be tedious and slow.

Comment: They both use the same datasource

Comment: are you trying to find that cell value in any column or other rows with a matching value in that particular column?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to build a dictionary, when you initialize your datagridview with your datasource, that makes correspond the row key (`AllegationsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value`) with the row index in the  `parentGrid`. Use the datasource, and not the datagrid, to build this dictionary.

You will be able to access fastly to the corresponding row.

Answer (score 0):

From comments: `They both use the same datasource`

I am not sure why a DGV the user *doesnt* interact with needs to have the `CurrentCell` kept in synch because if they are bound to the same datasource, changes to A are seen in B immediately.  Nonetheless:

```
Private Sub dgv1_CellClick(sender As Object, 
               e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv1.CellContentClick
    If dgv2.Rows.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

    dgv2.CurrentCell = dgv2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
End Sub
```

Here, `dgv1` is the user grid, dgv2 is the other ("parent" in your code?).

The For/Each iteration is not needed if they share a DS because the same data will be at each row and each column index. It will work even if the user has reordered the columns because the column index stays the same, just an internal `DisplayIndex` changes.

This uses the row and column indices from the `DataGridViewCellEventArgs` to set the `CurrentCell`.  The `Exit Sub` is to account for starting up when one may have rows and not the other.

You may want to play with which event to respond to. `CellContentClick` seems least useful: if they click on any cell whitespace, it doesnt fire.  It will also crash if the can click on a cell in the parent/dgv2 grid.  `CellEnter` will also crash if they click on dgv2 directly.

`CellClick` seems to work okay, but there is the very slightest of delays before they synch up.